# How do I force the motherboard (instead of external gpus) to provide the monitor output?

Tags: linux, gpu, nixos

I built a computer that has a motherboard and a couple of gpus in order to use the gpus for computation-intensive tasks.

Before plugging in the gpus, I was able to operate a monitor by plugging its vga into the motherboard. However, after plugging in the gpus, now no signal is output from the motherboard vga port and I just get "no signal" on the monitor.

Perhaps I could connect the monitor to receive output from one of the gpus, but I don't want to do that. I just want to continue to get video output via the motherboard so the gpus can be used exclusively for computing tasks.

How do I configure the motherboard to provide video output, despite the gpus being connected for computing work?

The OS is linux, specifically nixos.

Comment: To clarify: you want to use the hardware on the motherboard for graphics, and the GPUs only for computing? Configure X to  use the motherboard hardware as main display. Have a look at `xrandr` and `xorg.conf`.

Comment: These GPUs are on separate video cards, that plug into the motherboard? I have a dedicated video card in my machine, but the built-in motherboard video out still works if the card is plugged in. It might be hardware-specific?